# Min/Max of dates in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

```js
var expenseDates = ["2018-02-06","2018-11-08","2018-11-10","2017-05-02","2017-05-02","2018-11-01"];

var sorted = expenseDates.slice()
.sort(function(a, b) {
   return new Date(a) - new Date(b);
});
    
console.log(sorted.pop()+    '--max');
console.log(sorted.shift()+  '--min');
```

Comment: Posting an image of your code or data is kind-of annoying because it's not possible to copy-paste in order to test it. Stackoverflow has ample facilities for rendering code directly in the question.

Comment: You're sorting your dates in ascending order, so `pop()` will retrieve the max one, not the min one (other way around for `shift()`).

Comment: @Pointy updated and found solution thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have convert it into date object as the date are in `YYYY-MM-DD` format which itself is in sorted order by `year => month => day`. So you just have to compare the input string as `localCompare`. First index is minimum date while the last index is maximum date

```
var expenseDates = ["2018-02-06","2018-11-08","2018-11-10","2017-05-02","2017-05-02","2018-11-01"];

    expenseDates = expenseDates.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    });

   console.log('--min => ',expenseDates[0]);
   console.log('--max => ', expenseDates[expenseDates.length -1]);
```

Working jsFiddle demo - https://jsfiddle.net/rpdon5cm/1/